# Save all button for Raptor Editor

Tags: javascript, button, editor

I have multiple editable blocks on a webpage (similar to https://www.raptor-editor.com/demo) that I can edit individually with the Raptor Editor. To save my changes however, I have to save the changes per block individually.

I am looking for a way to implement a seperate button "Save all", which loops through all unsaved changes and saves them.
Any ideas or code examples?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The save rest plugin for raptor save each block individually to its own URL.

- https://github.com/PANmedia/raptor-editor/blob/master/src/plugins/save/save-rest.js
- https://www.raptor-editor.com/documentation/tutorials/save-rest
- https://github.com/PANmedia/raptor-example/blob/master/examples/save-rest/example.php